# Change windows command title programmatically and permanently

Tags: python, windows

I can change the console title form a python program using `ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW(some_new_title)` but as soon as the program exits (or crashes) the title reverts to whatever it was before. Is there some way to make the new title stay even after the program exits? The reason I want this is because I have quite a lot of different python scripts running on different consoles and I want to be able to quickly identify them by name in my taskbar. This works perfectly while the programs are actually running, but if a few of them either finish or crash then I have a collection of console titles in my taskbar which are all identical.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do that as the python process runs within the command prompt so while it can alter it while running, once it exits (gracefully or otherwise) it returns control back to the prompt. I'm not a windows developer but I imagine there's a way to pass the name of the prompt when you start it and then run the Python process within that? Or there might be some flag to alter the parent process' title permanently? Just hints.... not a windows dev...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the clue from @Jon Clements...
Instead of launching my python script with this:

```
python myscript.py
```

I write a batch file mypy.bat which contains...

```
title %*
python %*
```

Then I run my script with:

```
mypy myscript.py
```

The name of the window remains as "myscript.py" even after the script exits.

Comment: This works because batch files are executed inside cmd.exe